Why do I see a wireframe when rendering with conservative rasterization and disabled Z writes?
I wrote a shader that implements most ShaderLab commands:

Rendering without anything fancy:

After enabling conservative rasterization:

After disabling Z write:

Ironically, that's exactly what I was looking for: a wireframe over the mesh!
So, why does that happen, and is this something I can truly rely on?

Conservative rasterization draws to every pixel the triangle even just slightly touches, including a range of uncertainty around the outside to account for rounding/snapping.
That means there's an extra little border of pixels around the perimeter of the triangle that will now get drawn to, when they wouldn't have under the default rasterizer: those pixels would "belong" to adjacent triangles, so we wouldn't draw them as part of this triangle to avoid double-covering pixels along the edge.
That double-covering is exactly what you're seeing here. With Z-write on, some of the double-covering gets skipped, because the first triangle to draw to that pixel reserved its Z depth, and the second sees that pixel as already occupied by a surface at the same or slightly closer depth. When you turn off the Z-write, you get double-covering of all the pixels along an edge shared between two visible triangles.
Note that you don't get outlines along the outer perimeter / silhouette edge of the object: there, the triangles on the other side of the edge are back-facing, so they're not drawn, and there's nothing to add the second pass of the double cover.

Good catch, I didn't notice the missing wireframe at edges. I ended up drawing a 2nd time using GL.wireframe = true; as it will just work.
